# Operating a Commutator as an observable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

I came across the *Baker-Hausdorff theorem* in my quantum mechanics course and wanted to know how an observable commutes with a commutator it was a part of.

Well if I have $[p,x]$, it should give me $-i\hbar$, but what about $[p,[p,x]]$?
Would it just give me zero?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right! Just check:
$$ p [p,x] = p (-i\hbar) = (-i\hbar) p = [p,x] p . $$
(Operators commute with c-numbers.)

Of course, in general $[A, [A,B]] \neq 0$, it can be anything.